# Probability Model

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I have the following probability model:

$(X_k|\text{ PastHistory}_{k-1}, \theta_0, \theta_1, \theta_2) \sim (\pi\cdot N(\theta_1+\theta_0\cdot X_{k-1},1)+(1-\pi)\cdot N(\theta_2+\theta_0\cdot X_{k-1},1))$

and $X_k=0.5X_{k-1}+\epsilon_k$ with $\epsilon_k \sim N(0,1)$

I've tried something like:

```
Sample[n_] := 
 Module[{lst},
  lst = {RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1/(1 - 0.5^2)]]};
  element = 1;
  While[element <= n,
    AppendTo[lst, 
      RandomVariate[
        TransformedDistribution[
         p*X1 + (1 - p) X2, {
         X1 \[Distributed] 
         NormalDistribution[θ1 + θ0*lst[[element]], 1], 
         X2 \[Distributed] 
           NormalDistribution[θ2 + θ0*lst[[element]], 1]
      }]]];
   element = element + 1;
    ];
 lst
 ];
```

Is this correct?

Comment: This way of collecting results using `AppendTo` is very slow. See also the Q&A [something faster than AppendTo in a loop](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/42957/4330)

Comment: Note also that `TransformedDistribution[p*X1 + (1 - p) X2, {X1 \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[θ1 + θ0*el, 1], X2 \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[θ2 + θ0*el, 1]}]` simplifies to `NormalDistribution[el θ0+p (θ1-θ2)+θ2,Sqrt[1+2 (-1+p) p]]`. It is better to put the simplified version in the code, otherwise this simplification will be done at each iteration.

Comment: Can you please explain the relevance of the equation $X_k=0.5X_{k-1}+\epsilon_k$ with $\epsilon_k \sim N(0,1)$? This seems to imply that `θ0 = 1/2` for instance. You seem to only use the first equation for $X_k$ in your code.

Comment: You're right Jacob. I've already managed to programme it, but in different way. Thanks anyway. ;)

Comment: You are welcome, sir :)