# Something faster than Do loops with AppendTo

Tags: performance-tuning

I am an "old" programmer used to *Fortran* and *Pascal*. I can't get rid of `For`, `Do` and `While` loops, but I know *Mathematica* can do things much faster!

I am using the following code

```
SeedRandom[3]
n = 10;
v1 = Range[n];
v2 = RandomReal[250., n];

a = {};
Do[
   Do[
    AppendTo[a, (v2[[i]] - v2[[j]])/(v1[[i]] - v1[[j]])
     ],
    {j, i - 1, 1, -1}], {i, n, 2, -1}
   ]; // Timing
```

If `n` is small, it runs fast enough, but for bigger `n` it slows down. I usually deal  with `n > 600`.

How can the code be made faster?

Comment: It isn't due to `Do`. It's `AppendTo`, which copies its argument on every call. Use `Sow`/`Reap` instead and you'll most likely find that your code runs fine as it is. Not to say that a functional alternative might not be faster and clearer, but if you find it easier to think procedurally, there are ways to improve performance without sacrificing that.

Comment: Another suggestion is to just get the result as a jigged array and flatten it at the end :
`b = Flatten[
    Table[Table[(v2[[i]] - v2[[j]])/(v1[[i]] - v1[[j]]), {j, i - 1, 
       1, -1}], {i, n, 2, -1}]]; // Timing`.

Comment: You posted this just as I was writing mine. I didn't mean to rip you off!

Comment: @WalkingRandomly No problem of course - well done.

Comment: Yes! Exactly! Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Closely related: [professionalize/optimize my code that calls a function](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/39263)

Comment: Would anyone mind if we rename this Q&A: "The dangers of using Append(To) in a loop" and clean it up, to make it as recognisable and easy to find as possible?

Comment: @Ymareth correctly points out that `v1` is not useful, as `v1[[i]] == i` for all `i`. I would suggest simply correcting this flaw in the question to make it as clean as possible.

Comment: I concur with @JacobAkkerboom; having a canonical pitfalls of `AppendTo` and some suggested alternatives would be helpful.  The `Sow`/`Reap` suggestion is not intuitive (IMHO).

Comment: I think I will make a new Q&A, so that we can make that one canonical. This will remove distractions like the existence of `v1` and comments. I hope we will close this question as a duplicate of the new one even if this sounds strange.

Answer (score 10):

A more functional approach:

```
a = With[{f = Subtract @@@ Subsets[Reverse@#, {2}] &}, f[v2]/f[v1]]
```

For a bit more speed you could do this:

```
ii = Join @@ Table[ConstantArray[i, i - 1], {i, n, 2, -1}];
jj = Join @@ Table[Range[j, 1, -1], {j, n - 1, 1, -1}];
a = Divide[Subtract[v2[[ii]], v2[[jj]]], Subtract[v1[[ii]], v1[[jj]]]];
```

Comment: +1, nice work. See my comment re: later subtraction.

Comment: At first I only looked at your second method, as you said this was faster. But now that I looked at the first method as well, it turns out that one is very slow :(.

Comment: @rasher, I assumed that the `v1` given in the question was an example and it would not generally be `Range[n]`, but it's a good point worth mentioning.

Answer (score 9):

As mentioned, the main issue is using `AppendTo` in loops like this. In this answer, I want to show that using `Compile` can make procedural code very fast. Below is a comparison of timings of all the answers, as well as the OPs code.

Here is a slight modification of the code by the OP. I have modified it because I wanted to focus on `AppendTo`, so I have cleaned it up a bit.

```
questionCode :=
  (
   qCRes = {};
   Do[AppendTo[qCRes, (v[[i]] - v[[j]])/(i - j)],
    {i, n, 2, -1}, {j, i - 1, 1, -1}]
   );
```

**Alternatives**

My code uses a compiled function, where code that is similar to that of the OP is compiled to C. If you do not have a C compiler, simply remove `CompilationTarget->"C"`. My code also uses undocumented functions, notably Internal'Bag. This is basically an implementation of a linked list structure, which is especially useful inside `Compile`.

```
jacobCfu =
  Compile[
   {{v, _Real, 1}},

   Block[
    {result, n},
    result = Internal`Bag[];
    n = Length@v;
    Do[Internal`StuffBag[result, (v[[i]] - v[[j]])/(i - j)], {i, n, 
      2, -1}, {j, i - 1, 1, -1}];
    Internal`BagPart[result, All]], CompilationTarget -> "C"
   ];

jacobCode :=
  (
   jacobRes = jacobCfu[v]
   );
```

Other answerers' code. This includes a slightly modified version of Simon Woods (SW) code I made (`sWCodeE`)

```
rasherCode1 :=
  (
   rasherRes1 = 
    Table[(v2[[i]] - v2[[j]])/(v1[[i]] - v1[[j]]), {i, n, 2, -1}, {j, 
       i - 1, 1, -1}] // Flatten
   );

rasherCode2 :=
  (
   rasherRes2 =
    Block[
     {s, i1, i2},
     s = Subsets[Range[n, 1, -1], {2}];
     {i1, i2} = {s[[All, 1]], s[[All, 2]]}; 
     Divide[Subtract[v2[[i1]], v2[[i2]]], i1 - i2]
     ]
   );

wRCode :=
  (
   wRRes = 
    Flatten[Table[(v2[[i]] - v2[[j]])/(v1[[i]] - v1[[j]]), {i, n, 
       2, -1}, {j, i - 1, 1, -1}]]
   );

sWCode1 :=
  (sWRes1 = 
    With[{f = Subtract @@@ Subsets[Reverse@#, {2}] &}, f[v2]/f[v1]]);

sWCode2 :=
  (
   sWRes2 =
    Block[
     {ii, jj},

     ii = Join @@ Table[ConstantArray[i, i - 1], {i, n, 2, -1}];
     jj = Join @@ Table[Range[j, 1, -1], {j, n - 1, 1, -1}];
     Divide[Subtract[v2[[ii]], v2[[jj]]], Subtract[v1[[ii]], v1[[jj]]]]
     ]
   );

sWCodeE :=
  (
   sWResE =
    Block[
     {ii, jj},
     ii = Join @@ Table[ConstantArray[i, i - 1], {i, n, 2, -1}];
     jj = Join @@ Table[Range[j, 1, -1], {j, n - 1, 1, -1}];
     Divide[Subtract[v2[[ii]], v2[[jj]]], Subtract[ii, jj]]
     ]
   );

lalmeiCode :=
 (
  (lalmeiRes = 
    First@Last@
      Reap[Scan[
        Function[{x}, 
         Sow[(v2[[x[[1]]]] - v2[[x[[2]]]])/(v1[[x[[1]]]] - 
              v1[[x[[2]]]])];], 
        Table[{i, j}, {i, n, 2, -1}, {j, i - 1, 1, -1}], {2}]])
  )
```

**Timing comparison functions**

```
timing = Function[Null, First@Timing@#, HoldAll];
timingAndName = 
  Function[Null, {timing@#, ToString@Unevaluated@#}, HoldAll];
timingsAndNamesTable = 
  Function[Null, TableForm[timingAndName /@ Unevaluated[{##}]], 
   HoldAll];

formattedTimingsAndComparison =
  Function[Null,
   Block[{timingTable},
    timingTable = timingsAndNamesTable@##;

    Column[
     {
      StringForm["Comparison for n = ``", n]
      ,
      timingTable
      ,
      If[
       SameQ @@ resultNames
       ,
       "results are equal"
       ,
       Row[{"results are ", Style["not ", Bold], "equal"}]
       ]
      }
     ,
     Spacings -> 2 ]
    ]
   ,
   HoldAll
   ];
```

**Initialisation**

```
initialize[nn_] :=
 (
  SeedRandom[3];
  n = nn;
  v = RandomReal[250., n];
  v1 = Range[n];
  v2 = v;
  )
```

**Timing comparison**

```
initialize[200];
resultNames = 
  Hold[qCRes, jacobRes, sWResE, sWRes2, wRRes, rasherRes1, 
   rasherRes1, rasherRes2, lalmeiRes];

formattedTimingsAndComparison[
 questionCode,
 jacobCode,
 sWCodeE,
 sWCode2,
 rasherCode2,
 wRCode,
 rasherCode1,
 lalmeiCode
 ]
```

Gives

> Comparison for n = 200
>
> ```
>  1.168769   questionCode
>  0.000674   jacobCode
>  0.001093   sWCodeE
>  0.001200   sWCode2
>  0.004740   rasherCode2
>  0.070625   wRCode
>  0.069372   rasherCode1
>  0.176819   lalmeiCode
> ```
>
> results are equal

Let's look at a larger value of `n` as well

```
initialize[1000]
resultNames = Hold[jacobRes, sWResE, sWRes2, rasherRes2];

formattedTimingsAndComparison[
 jacobCode,
 sWCodeE,
 sWCode2,
 rasherCode2
 ]
```

Gives

> Comparison for n = 1000
>
> ```
> 0.020356    jacobCode
> 0.052107    sWCodeE
> 0.110584    sWCode2
> 0.526762    rasherCode2
> ```
>
> results are equal

Comment: it seems the same to me.

Comment: @lalmei see the edit :)

Comment: C beats mathematica? Who would have thought it...
Simon's fine idea can be further improved by removing the last subtraction, probably unbeatable using pure MMA and non-compiled, documented functions. Well done, SW.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom thanks for the inclusion :) though I wasn't going for speed. Nice answer btw! What is Internal`StuffBag ? Is it an undocumented function ?

Comment: @lalmei no problemo! Yeah, it is an undocumented function, as are Internal'Bag and Internal'BagPart, or any function in the `Context` Internal for that matter. It is basically an implementation of a linkedlist data structure, which can (even) be used in `Compile`. I quite like it :).

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom very nice answer indeed. +1

Answer (score 5):

Just changing it to something like:

```
Table[(v2[[i]] - v2[[j]])/(v1[[i]] - v1[[j]]), {i, n, 2, -1}, {j, i - 1, 1, -1}] // Flatten
```

Should net you a nice boost. Edit - oops, ninja'd

About twice as fast as any so far on large N:

```
s = Subsets[Range[n, 1, -1], {2}];
{i1, i2} = {s[[All, 1]], s[[All, 2]]};
result = Divide[Subtract[v2[[i1]], v2[[i2]]], i1 - i2];
```

Edit - Simon beat me to the faster way to create indexes. His can be improved by removing the whole latter subtraction, as in mine, netting his a 25% boost in my tests.

Answer (score 4):

Your version:

```
SeedRandom[3]
n = 250;
v1 = Range[n];
v2 = RandomReal[250., n];

a = {};
Do[
   Do[
    AppendTo[a,
     (v2[[i]] - v2[[j]])/(v1[[i]] - v1[[j]])],
    {j, i - 1, 1, -1}], {i, n, 2, -1}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

on my machine this takes 1.85 seconds

This version

```
AbsoluteTiming[A = Flatten[
  Table[(v2[[i]] - v2[[j]])/(i-j), {i, n, 2, -1}, {j, 
    i - 1, 1, -1}]] 
    ]
```

Takes 0.112 seconds

They give the same result.

```
In[75]:= a == A

Out[75]= True
```

Comment: You can also replace v1[[i]]-v1[[j]] with i-j.  There is no need for v1.

Comment: Good point. Corrected.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example using Reap and Sow.

It is a bit overkill in this case, but if you need to append only some of the values it should go much faster with Reap and Sow, or if you need to perform other functions while appending.

```
Last@Reap[
Scan[Function[{x}, 
     Sow[(v2[[x[[1]]]] - v2[[x[[2]]]])/(v1[[x[[1]]]] -v1[[x[[2]]]])]; 
     ],
     Table[{i, j}, {i, n, 2, -1}, {j, i - 1, 1, -1}], 
     {2}]]//Timing
```

> {0.00062, {{124.857, 17.9221, 27.095, 23.4391, 36.1562, 31.8519, 
>      19.882, 27.9697, 11.8103, -89.0129, -21.7861, -10.3669, 13.9809, 
>      13.2509, 2.38619, 14.1286, -2.3205, 45.4407, 28.956, 48.3122, 
>      38.8168, 20.666, 31.3189, 10.0641, 12.4714, 49.748, 36.6089, 
>      14.4723, 28.4945, 4.16804, 87.0246, 48.6777, 15.1393, 32.5003, 
>      2.50737, 10.3307, -20.8033, 14.3255, -18.6219, -51.9374, 
>      16.3229, -28.2728, 84.5831, -16.4406, -117.464}}}