# Alternative ways to AppendTo and Delete in a While loop

Tags: performance-tuning

Is there an alternative way to do `AppendTo` and `Delete` and also replace `k0` during every update? I want to avoid the 3- `CopyTensor`s in the following code which probably are the reason behind the memory and performance problems for large values of `n`.

```
f = Compile[{{n, _Integer}},
   Module[{Fk = Table[RandomReal[{0, 1}], {5}, {n}], k0 = Table[RandomReal[{0, 1}], {n}], TT = 0.1, ksum, i = 0},
    While[TT > 0 ,
     ksum = Total@Fk;
     k0 = MapThread[Min[#1, #2 RandomReal[{0, 1}]] &, {k0, ksum}];
     TT = Round[Total@k0, 0.01]; i++;
     Fk = Delete[Fk, {1}];
     AppendTo[Fk, k0];
    ]; i
   ]
  ]
```

Comment: Related: [Something faster than Do loops with AppendTo](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/42957)

Comment: I have seen it before, where the AppendTo in each iteration is independent of results from previous iterations unlike in this case.

Comment: To what extent is your code dependent on ordering? You might try just using `Fk[[1]] = k0` without the deletion, if there is no order dependency (I cannot tell for certain although i suspect it has no such dependency). If there is a dependency on the ordering then you could maintain a "current" index and iterate from there modulo the length e.g. if length is 6 and current is 4 one would iterate over elements 4,5,6,1,2,3 in that order. Standard trick.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I have multiple `AppendTo` in my original code (http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/50599/garbage-collection-with-nminimize-and-performance). For some, order is not important and for others it is important. For the former, if I do `Fk[[1]]=k0`, then I will be only replacing that one row every subsequent iteration. The 4 other rows stay the same all the time. However, I need that as a new row is added at the bottom, top row is deleted. Latter case not clear to me. In the above code, `Fk` is always 5X10. How do you get 6 elements and in that order. Please elaborate.

Comment: Daniel have written how to iterate using "current" index. You have it already in your code it's `i`. I think using `Fk[[Mod[i, 5] + 1]] = k0;` instead of `Fk = Delete[Fk, {1}]; AppendTo[Fk, k0];` would do the trick.

Comment: `RotateLeft` and then set the last element (previously the first) to the new value. Or the other way around, if you like. Dan's suggestion is more efficient if you don't mind keeping track of where you're supposed to start from.

Comment: @OleksandrR. `RotateLeft` is awesome. +1

Comment: @DanielLichtblau. Thanks to @jkuczm, I got what you are inferring..That is the best!! Wish I can do more than +1. I have only 1 `copyTensor` remaining. Do you have any thoughts on how I can get rid of even that!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have one improvement to suggest.  Instead of finding the minimums with `MapThread`, use a compiled version that threads itself over the lists:

```
mappedmin = Compile[{{x, _Real, 1}},
   Min[x],
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True];
```

We can compare using this with the OP's and with [Daniel Lichtblau's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/51/daniel-lichtblau) improvement.

```
fmm = Compile[{{n, _Integer}}, 
   Module[{Fk = Table[RandomReal[{0, 1}], {5}, {n}], 
     k0 = Table[RandomReal[{0, 1}], {n}], TT = 0.1, ksum, i = 0}, 
    While[TT > 0,
     ksum = Total@Fk;
     k0 = mappedmin[Transpose@{k0, RandomReal[{0, 1}, n] ksum}];
     TT = Round[Total@k0, 0.01]; i++;
     Fk = Delete[Fk, {1}];
     AppendTo[Fk, k0];]; i],
   CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}];

f[10^6]   // AbsoluteTiming
fmm[10^6] // AbsoluteTiming
(*
  {30.814108, 193}
  {18.011360, 193}
*)
```

If `Parallelization` is turned off, it runs about 1+ sec. slower.

Here is an implementation of Daniel's suggestion, similar to [rasher's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/11467/rasher) `f2c`, without and with `mappedmin`.  (I also got rid of the intermediate variable `ksum`, since that was a source of one of the `CopyTensor` calls, and used vectorized multiplication.)

```
dl = Compile[{{n, _Integer}}, 
   Module[{Fk = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {5, n}], 
     k0 = RandomReal[{0, 1}, n], TT = 0.1, i = 0},
    While[TT > 0,
     i++;
     k0 = MapThread[Min[#1, #2 RandomReal[{0, 1}]] &, {k0, Total@Fk}];
     TT = Round[Total@k0, 0.01];
     Fk[[Mod[i, 5, 1]]] = k0;
     ]; i]
   ];
dlmm = Compile[{{n, _Integer}}, 
   Module[{Fk = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {5, n}], 
     k0 = RandomReal[{0, 1}, n], TT = 0.1, i = 0},
    While[TT > 0,
     i++;
     k0 = mappedmin[Transpose@{k0, RandomReal[{0, 1}, n] Total@Fk}];
     TT = Round[Total@k0, 0.01];
     Fk[[Mod[i, 5, 1]]] = k0;
     ]; i],
   CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}];

dl[10^6]   // AbsoluteTiming
dlmm[10^6] // AbsoluteTiming
(*
  {25.698229, 193}
  {13.146244, 193}
*)
```

Again `mappedmin` saves about 12 sec. (40% of the timing of the OP's `f`).

If we compare `mappedmin` with `MapThread`, we see it takes about 55% of the time that a compiled `MapThread` takes, which does not completely account for the 12 sec. saving above:

```
mapthreadmin = Compile[{{x1, _Real, 1}, {x2, _Real, 1}},
   MapThread[Min, {x1, x2}]
   ];

data = RandomReal[1, {2, 10^6}];
Do[mapthreadmin[data[[1]], data[[2]]], {18}] // AbsoluteTiming // First
Do[mappedmin[Transpose@data], {18}]          // AbsoluteTiming // First
(*
  1.010342
  0.549180
)*
```

Comment: +1 for the analysis (this deserves more votes!). Interestingly, I tested second here, slower than I expected (caveat: on loungebook). 
My hunch (lacking an OP explanation of goal) is instead of the machinations, this problem can be represented as a compound distribution sum, and just pull random variates from that, which I'd venture would be quite fast.

Comment: @rasher  Weekends can be slow, especially if the weather is nice or there's a World Cup on. Yours deserves more votes, too.  (I already upvoted.)

Comment: @MichaelE2. Excellent analysis and a nice idea to Parallelize `Min`. +1

Answer (score 8):

Table is unnecessary with RandomReal and just adds additional time

```
n = 10; m = 10^6;

(SeedRandom[100];
   Table[RandomReal[{0, 1}], {5}, {n}]) ==
 (SeedRandom[100];
   Fk = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {5, n}])
```

> True

```
(SeedRandom[100];
   Table[RandomReal[{0, 1}], {n}]) ==
 (SeedRandom[100];
   k0 = RandomReal[{0, 1}, n])
```

> True

Alternate ways of deleting first list in Fk

```
Delete[Fk, {1}] == Drop[Fk, 1] == Rest[Fk]
```

> True

```
Timing[Do[Delete[Fk, {1}], {m}];]
```

> {3.029095, Null}

```
Timing[Do[Drop[Fk, 1], {m}];]
```

> {1.079259, Null}

```
Timing[Do[Rest[Fk], {m}];]
```

> {1.084052, Null}

Faster alternative to AppendTo

```
Off[Set::write]

Timing[Do[e1 = AppendTo[Rest[Fk], k0], {m}];]
```

> {11.440818, Null}

```
On[Set::write]

Timing[Do[e2 = Flatten[{Rest[Fk], {k0}}, 1], {m}];]
```

> {6.973775, Null}

```
e1 == e2
```

> True

```
f = Compile[{{n, _Integer}}, Module[{Fk = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {5, n}], k0 = RandomReal[{0, 1}, n],
 TT = 0.1, ksum, i = 0}, While[TT > 0, ksum = Total@Fk;
 k0 = MapThread[Min[#1, #2 RandomReal[{0, 1}]] &, {k0, ksum}];
 TT = Round[Total@k0, 0.01]; i++;
 Fk = Flatten[{Rest[Fk], {k0}}, 1]];]; i]
```

Comment: I like the alternatives for `Delete` and `AppendTo`, but using `Flatten[{Rest[Fk], {k0}}, 1]` in the pace of `Fk = Delete[Fk, {1}]; AppendTo[Fk, k0];` is giving an error during execution. Weird!!. It says "CompiledFunction::cflist: Nontensor object generated; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation. >>"

Comment: @brama The function f above appears to compile without an error.

Comment: Agree. Thank you.  I like your alternative ways. But, your code gives 2 `copytensor`s and 1 `MainEvaluate` (my code had 3 `copytensor`). I am basically looking for a way to get rid of those, because, my original code (I only show a sample test code here) has 38 `copytensor` and I was trying to find ways to get rid of them.

Comment: I think you really ought to test the timings with each of the three methods inside `Compile`. I see only a small difference between them.

Answer (score 7):

Sticking with the machinations of your code (might be worthwhile to explain *what* you're trying to accomplish and the over-arching problem, might be an elegant way to realize it), here's a modification that does away with one of the `CopyTensor`, and is 50-100% faster:

```
f = Compile[{{n, _Integer}},
  Module[{Fk = RandomReal[1, {5, n}], k0 = RandomReal[1, n], TT = 0.1, ksum, i = 0},
   While[TT > 0,
       ksum = Total@Fk;
       Fk = RotateLeft[Fk];
       k0 = Fk[[-1]] = MapThread[Min, {k0, ksum RandomReal[1, n]}];
       TT = Round[Total@k0, 0.01];
       i++;];i]]
```

Updates:

This cuts down to only one `CopyTensor`, and is about 25%+ faster again than above solution:

```
f2c = Compile[{{n, _Integer}},
   Module[{Fk = RandomReal[1, {5, n}], k0 = RandomReal[1, n], TT = 0.1, ksum, i = 0},
    While[TT > 0,
     k0 = Fk[[Mod[i, 5, 1]]] = MapThread[Min, {k0, Total@Fk  RandomReal[1, n]}];
     TT = Round[Total@k0, 0.01];
     i++;];i]];
```

And this has no `CopyTensor` operations. Seems slightly faster than first above, not quite as fast as second, did not check memory utilization. Note this internally shuffles things - result is the same, but if you need to poke at internals, take that into account:

```
f2d = Compile[{{n, _Integer}},
   Module[{Fk = RandomReal[1, {6, n}], TT = 0.1, i = 0},
    While[TT > 0,
     Fk[[-1]] = 
      Fk[[Mod[i, 5, 1]]] = 
       MapThread[
        Min, {Fk[[-1]], (Total@(Fk[[;; -2]]))  RandomReal[1, n]}];
     TT = Round[Total@Fk[[-1]], 0.01];
     i++;];i]];
```

Comment: The original code is posted at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/50599/garbage-collection-with-nminimize-and-performance?noredirect=1#comment149400_50599 I will make these changed in that code, but will it be possible to getrid of even those two `copytensor`s?

Comment: @brama: Did not look at the "original code" - again, I'd rather an explanation of goal than to "decode" someone's code. In any case, see updates to my answer.